# Android Ksoap invalid Message body

Tags: android, ksoap

I have an android application , I'm trying to call .net web services using `ksoap` library , but i have a problem , when I run my project I get error like this :

> SoapFault - faultcode: 'a:InternalServiceFault' faultstring: 'Error
>   in deserializing body of request message for operation 'yemeksorgusu'.
>   OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to
>   find node type 'Element' with name 'yemeksorgusu' and namespace
>   'mozaikkebap.com.tr'. Found node type 'Element' with name 'anyType'
>   and namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'' faultactor: 'null'
>   detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@263fd05

Answer (score 0):

I think you're soap response is in this format [image: Soap Service Response]
I your using soap services in your android application than you should go through this tutorial
[This is for sample code](https://trinitytuts.com/load-data-from-soap-web-service-in-android-application/)

Comment: hi , i try this tutorial bu i failed again :/

Comment: hi , i made some changes and now getting this error :)

Comment: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: END_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body (position:END_TAG </{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}s:Fault>@1:709 in java.io.InputStreamReader@8058dbc)

Comment: i add property like that ;         
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("username", "asdf");
        request.addProperty("Pass", "asdasd");.......................